# Unit test service that returns promise Angularjs Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, promise

EDITED per Michal Charemza post.

I have a service that represents angularui modal dialog:

```
app.factory("dialogFactory", function($modal, $window, $q) {

    function confirmDeleteDialog() {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "../application/factories/confirmDeleteDialog.htm",
        controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {

            $scope.ok = function() {
                $modalInstance.close("true");
            };

            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $modalInstance.dismiss("false");
            };
        }
    });


    return modalInstance.result.then(function(response) {
        return 'My other success result';
    }, function(response) {
        return $q.reject('My other failure reason');
    });

};

    return {
        confirmDeleteDialog: confirmDeleteDialog
    };

});
```

On calling the delete method if the user has clicked Ok from the dialog `requestNotificationChannel.deleteMessage(id)` is executed.

```
$scope.deleteMessage = function(id) {
        var result = dialogFactory.confirmDeleteDialog();

        result.then(function(response) {
            requestNotificationChannel.deleteMessage(id);
        });
    };
```

The problem is I am not able to unit test this.

This is my test. I have correctly injected the q service but I am not sure what should I return from `"confirmDeleteDialog"` spy...

```
describe("has a delete method that should call delete message notification", function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            spyOn(dialogFactory, "confirmDeleteDialog").and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

            spyOn(requestNotificationChannel, "deleteMessage");

            $scope.deleteMessage(5);
            deferred.resolve();

            it("delete message notification is called", function() {
                expect(requestNotificationChannel.deleteMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
        });
```

But I am receiving `expected spy deleteMessage to have been called`. Which means that the `result.then`... part is not executed. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To mock a function that returns a promise, it will need to also return a promise, which then needs to be resolved as a separate step.

In your case the `deferred.resolve()` you pass to the spy needs to be replaced with `deferred.promise`, and the deferred.resolve() performed separately.

```
beforeEach(function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  spyOn(dialogFactory, "confirmDeleteDialog").and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
  spyOn(requestNotificationChannel, "deleteMessage");
  $scope.deleteMessage(5);
  deferred.resolve();
  $rootScope.$digest();
});

it("delete message notification is called", function() {
  expect(requestNotificationChannel.deleteMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I suspect you also need to call `$rootScope.$digest()`, as Angular's promise implementation is tied to the digest loop.

Also, slightly unrelated to your question, but I don't think you need to create your own deferred object in `confirmDeleteDialog`. The (anti) pattern you're using has been labelled 'The Forgotten Promise', as in http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/

When is simpler, uses less code, and I think that allows better error handling, you can just return the promise that the `$modal` service creates:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({...});
return modalInstance.result;
```

If you want to modify what the calling function sees, in terms of resolved/rejected values, you can create a chained promise by returning the result of `then`:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({...});
return modalInstance.result.then(function(successResult) {
  return 'My other success result';
}, function(failureReason) {
  return $q.reject('My other failure reason');
});
```

You would usually want to do this if you don't want to expose the inner-workings of a function  to its caller. This is analogous to the concept of re-throwing an exception in synchronous programming.

Comment: I've added a part about `$rootScope.$digest()`

Comment: Yes, `$digest()` is definitely required here.