# how to test $http call in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test my **$http** request using karma and jasmine.I make one controller and inject a service .In service I call $http service.I need to test that service how I will test this service this is my controller.

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('first',function($scope,data){
    $scope.name='test';
    data.getData().then(function(data){
          console.log(data);
    })

}).factory('data',function($http){
    return{
        getData:getData
    }

    function getData(){
             return $http.get('data.json').success(successCall).error(errorcallback)
    }

    function   successCall(data){
          return data
    }
    function   errorcallback(data){
        return data
    }
})
```

here is plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/POryyDUc8bvvfvI5Oap7?p=preview

i start like this

```
describe('http controller test', function () {

    var $rootScope,
        $scope,
        controller;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('app')  ;

        inject(function($injector){
            $rootScope  =  $injector.get('$rootScope') ;
            $scope=$rootScope.$new();
            controller =$injector.get('$controller')('first',{$scope:$scope})
        })
    })

    describe('Init value',function(){
        it('check name value',function(){
            expect($scope.name).toEqual('test');
        })

    })

    it('it should be true',function(){
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();

    })
})
```

could you please tell me how to write test when there is dependency of service in controller ?? how to test $http request in jasmine?in my controller there is a dependency of a service .how to inject this in my test file?

Comment: If you want to test the service and the request to the server, use $httpBackend: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: yes I studied ..but I understand little bit ..could you please change y example

Comment: please use this tool http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/E64Se/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the `data` service this way:

```
 describe('http controller test', function () {
    var $rootScope,
        $scope,
        data,
        controller;

     beforeEach(module('app'));

     beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $state, _data_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        state = $state;
        data = _data_;
        controller = $controller('first',{$scope:$scope});
     });

     it('data service should be defined',function(){
         expect(data).toBeDefined();
     });
});
```

There is an example regarding testing promises using Angular and Jasmine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905581/unit-test-service-that-returns-promise-angularjs-jasmine) and an example regarding testing $http promises [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126372/angularjs-testing-factory-that-returns-http-promises) using $httpBackend.

Comment: is there any online test editor  to test this ?  I am studying there is $httpbackend  ? can we use that httpbackend ?

Comment: Many times I saw this jasmine keyword spyOn spyOn ...? what is that

Comment: if httpbackend  and spyOn is necessary for $http request why didn't you use

Answer (score 0):

$httpbackend is what you need.

[API Reference / ngMock / service components in ngMock / $httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

Here is a snippet from that page.

```
    describe('MyController', function() {
   var $httpBackend, $rootScope, createController, authRequestHandler;

   // Set up the module
   beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

   beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
     // Set up the mock http service responses
     $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
     // backend definition common for all tests
     authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', '/auth.py')
                            .respond({userId: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});

     // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)
     $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
     // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
     var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

     createController = function() {
       return $controller('MyController', {'$scope' : $rootScope });
     };
   }));


   afterEach(function() {
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
   });


   it('should fetch authentication token', function() {
     $httpBackend.expectGET('/auth.py');
     var controller = createController();
     $httpBackend.flush();
   });
```