# Check internal variables in a function using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am using Jasmine and Karma for unit testing in my AngularJS app. I need to check value of internal variables in controller function.

Here is my controller.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('testApp',[])
        .controller('testController', testController);

    function testController($http, $scope, $timeout) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.getTestValues = getTestValues;

        function getTestValues(){

            vm.serverError = undefined;
            vm.priceList = [];

            $http.get('https://example.com/api/getPrice').then(function(response) {

                vm.priceList = response.data;

                vm.value = vm.priceList[0].itemValue;

                vm.totalValue = vm.value * 10;              

            }).catch(function(e){
                vm.serverError = 'Server Error';
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Here is my test code

```
describe('Test Controller', function() {
  beforeEach(module('testApp')); 

  var ctrl;

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller){

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('testController', { $scope: scope });
  }));


  describe('vm.value', function() {
    it('Should be ', function() {     

        ctrl.getTestValues();

        console.log(ctrl.priceList);


    });
  });  

});
```

`console.log(ctrl.priceList);` prints `[]`.

How could I access values in `vm.priceList`, `vm.value` and `vm.totalValue`?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: one suggestion: dont write tests for angularJs anymore. no upgrade possibility for angular 2+ and the things you can test are very limited, except you mock all da things, which is not the point of interest in tests ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$http.get` is an async call. You will have to use `$httpBackend` for unit testing a http service.

You can go through the following links to explore more.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

[how to test $http call in angular js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359052/how-to-test-http-call-in-angular-js)